# Unpublish article based on non date type field

Tags: 8, nodes, rules

So, I know that you need Rules to unpublish articles (after a certain time) based on date fields (https://groups.drupal.org/node/240678#comment-782543). But is this also possible with non date fields? When the user creates an article there should be a select list with items like `1 month`, `3 months`, `6 months`. After submitting the article is saved as unpublished, it is moderated and published by an admin and should then automatically be unpublished after the period selected by the user.

Comment: I think you will have to write some custom code. Have you experience in developing custom modules?

Comment: Unfortunately not, just a little bit with hooks in the theme file

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write custom code you can use the https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler module.

Quoting the description: "This module gives content editors the ability to schedule nodes to be published and unpublished at specified dates and times in the future "

Comment: I'm already using this module, but the problem is that the max. time can't be restricted